# Program listening to a stream of data in python

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, listener, python-multithreading

I want to create a function in Python that listens constantly to a stream of data and acts when a condition is met.

To simulate the stream of data I defined a function

```
import numpy as np

def constant_stream():
    stream_of_numbers = np.random.rand(100)
    for n in stream_of_numbers :
        print(n)
```

Now I want to create a function stream_listener that constantly listens to this stream of data and passes the data on to another function if a certain condition is met. For the sake of the example stream above let's say the stream_listener passes the data on if the number is bigger than 0.75.
I think something like the code below should work.

```
import Thread

the_thread = Thread(target=constant_stream)
the_thread.start()
stream_listener()
thread.join()
```

How can I define the function stream_listener accordingly?

To summarize my problem is the following: I have a constant stream of data (in the above example some random numbers). Now I want to create a function that listens to this stream of data and calls another function (i.e. passing the data from the stream on) in case a certain condition is met (above if the number is >0.75). Now while this data is passed on and handled somewhere else in the program, the stream_listener continues to listen to the stream of data and (potentially) passes some more data along. I tried something with asyncio.sleep(0) but my problem was that the program just non stop listened and never passed the data. Please feel free to ask for more clarification in case anything about the problem remains unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `np` is an alias for `numpy`, then couldn't you simplify that first line of your `constant_stream()` function by writing `stream_of_numbers=np.random.rand(100)`?

Comment: @SolomonSlow, true. I edited the first post and clarified that np is for numpy. Thanks!

Comment: Can you say more about your final goal. You say you want `stream_listener()` to listen to a "stream of data." What is that ultimately going to look like? Will the "stream" be a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)? Will it be a [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)? Will it be some other data type? There's a number of different ways to feed a stream of data to a function, but without knowing more about your goal, it's hard to say which one best simulates the environment in which your `stream_listener()` is supposed to run.

Comment: P.S., Are you familiar with Python [_generators_](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)?

Comment: @SolomonSlow the stream will be a socket.

Comment: OK, I won't attempt a detailed answer then because I have never used sockets in a Python program, but my approach would be to create a class that mimics a socket well enough to be used by your `stream_listener()`,\* and if it only has to return random data, then it would just generate those random numbers as needed each time it was called.

Comment: \* Python is a [_duck typed language_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), so you'd only need to implement those methods that `stream_listener()` actually calls. probably just `recv(...)` or `recvfrom(...)` or whichever one best fits your application.